# how do i get the latest tweets feed of the twitter user community,

Tags: php, javascript, twitter

is there anyway to get a feed latest tweets of the whole twitter community through the twitter API?

i have come across articles that explain how to get the status feed of a specific user or users. but i am trying to get a feed of about 10 tweets of the latest tweets by the whole twitter user community to display on the homepage of a twitter app i am working on.

is there anyway to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the sample stream to get a random sample of about 1% of all tweets 
http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api_methods#statuses-sample

Phirehose provides one PHP library for this, but be there are some errors in it that are reported in the Issues tab but not yet fixed.
http://code.google.com/p/phirehose/